# Find Last Row on sql using condition

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns `ID` and `Count` as below:

```
ID   Count
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    1
6    2
7    1
8    1
9    1
10   2
```

I need result as below:

```
ID   EndID
1    1 
2    4
5    6
7    7
8    8 
9    10
```

Logic behind the result is: `StartID` have count 1 and `EndID` is `Id` of row before next `Count = 1`. Here `ID` 1 begin and end with 1 and `ID` 2 begin and end in `ID` 4 before next `Count 1`. And similarly it goes on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data in your question, this works:

```
select t.id,
       (select min(t2.id) - 1
        from t t2
        where t2.id > t.id and t2.count = 1
       ) as EndId
from t
where t.count = 1;
```

This does assume that there are no gaps in the ids.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you have `t2.id > t.id and t2.id > t.id` where you want it to be `t2.id > t.id and t2.count = 1` I guess. Still that wouldn't find the end ID 10 for ID 9.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . Thank you very much; your comment is quite helpful.  I wish Stack Exchange discouraged anonymous downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

We don't know `RDBMS` you use, so this is the standard version:

```
SELECT id, COALESCE((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tableName 
                     WHERE id < (SELECT MIN(id) FROM tableName t2 
                             WHERE t2.id > t1.id AND t2.c = 1 )), 
                    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableName)) AS endid
FROM tableName t1 WHERE c = 1
```

Without `COALESCE` it looks like:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tableName 
            WHERE id < (SELECT MIN(id) FROM tableName t2 WHERE t2.id > t1.id AND t2.c = 1 ))
FROM tableName t1 WHERE c = 1
```

and results in:

```
1   1
2   4
5   6
7   7
8   8
9   NULL
```

That's why you need the last `COALESCE` part. The idea is to select minimal `ID` that is greater then outer query `ID` and then based on that find the maximal `ID` that is less then minimal `ID`. So you can use it even when ids contain gaps in it.

Comment: Nitpicking: that is not standard SQL  because `@t` is an invalid identifier in standard SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, oh I forgot to change those. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't use keywords for column names. I use `cnt` instead of `count` in below queries. You'd have to build groups for which you'd find the start and end value. If ID is consecutive with no gaps, then use:

```
select min(id) as startid, max(id) as endid
from
(
  select id, cnt, id - cnt as groupkey
  from mytable
) grouped
group by groupkey
order by min(id);
```

else use:

```
select min(id) as startid, max(id) as endid
from
(
  select id, cnt, row_number() over (order by id) - cnt as groupkey
  from mytable
) grouped
group by groupkey
order by min(id);
```

(Provided your DBMS features the ROW_NUMBER function of course. ROW_NUMBER is standard SQL, so many DBMS have it.)